# Does Spark Filter/Predicate Pushdown not working as intended in ORC file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

While "spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown" is equal to false (by default). Following statement took 3 minutes to execute.

```
val result = spark.read.schema(schema).orc("s3a://......./*")
result.select("a","b").where(col("a")===1318138224).explain(extended = true)
result.select("a","b").where(col("a")===1318138224).show()
```

At physical plan it says ;  **PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(a), EqualTo(a,1318138224)]**

So even if "filterPushdown" disabled by default by looking at  "PushedFilters" statement I thought spark somehow pushes down filters.

But after setting  spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown to "true" same code snippet took about 30 seconds. **Weird part is that physical plan was same**.

So I looked at "Stages" section at SparkUI and amount of input sizes were different.

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", false)
[image: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", false)]

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", true)
[image: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", true)]

So I feel like for reading orc files even if PushedFilters at Physical filled with some parameters(not empty) it doesn't mean Spark actually do pushdown predicate/filters ?

Or is there a point that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2):

The query plan is not affected by `filterPushdown` config (for either parquet or orc). Spark always tries to push filters to the source. The config controls whether source is allowed to apply the data skipping. Sometimes even when the config is set to true, there could be some cases where data skipping is not happening (due to bugs, or columns stats were incorrect or types not supported).

You can also check "number of output rows" in the SQL tab in web ui.

It is the number of rows read after predicate pushdown & partition pruning.

```
Scan parquet

number of files read: 1
scan time total (min, med, max )
18.7 s (12 ms, 214 ms, 841 ms )
metadata time: 0 ms
size of files read: 783.9 MiB
number of output rows: 100,000,000
```